# Visual Studio: check for installed applications in path

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have a Visual Studio 2015 project that uses cmake to get the source subversion repo details.  I have the project configured to run on each build and it works fine as long as cmake is installed.

Is there a way to setup a Visual Studio project to check for cmake in the path and provide a user friendly error message that cmake should be installed or put in the path?

The current error message I get when cmake is not installed just says something like 'The command cmake.exe ... exited with code 9009'.

Comment: how about adding pre build step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Exec task in your project to test.

```
<Target Name="CheckCmake" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <Exec Command='where cmake' IgnoreExitCode='true'>
        <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode"/>
    </Exec>
    <Error Text="cmake.exe could not be found. Verify that it is installed and in the path." Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' > '0'" />
</Target>
```

Add this chunk of code before the '</Project>' tag in your project file (.vcxproj, .vbproj, .vcproj, etc...) and it should execute before the build.

[image: Build output window]

Comment: How do I add an exec task to to my project? Most of my projects are C++ projects.

Comment: You should be able to add it to the .vcxproj file that defines your project. If the project is open in visual studio: you can right click the project, click Unload Project, right click the project, click Edit {projectName}... then reload the project into the solution when you are finished.

Comment: Tried adding it to the project root element and reloaded the project file.  Can't see anything different though. When does the new target run, or should I add it somewhere?

Comment: Place it at the bottom of the project file, just before the </Project>